# Are there technical reasons to avoid creating highly tangled package dependencies in large Java projects?

Tags: java, dependency-management

I'm new to modern Java compilers and Virtual Machines, so I'm curious, what technical issues do large Java projects (5000+ sizable classes) encounter, during compilation and at runtime, as the gordian knot of package dependencies grows?

In large C++ projects, you can get yourself into technical trouble (all maintainability concerns aside) if you stray far from an acyclic library (or package) dependency graph in large projects.

Some examples

- compilation can run out of memory if most of a source tree is included
- linking can too if too many object archives are included (object archives generally correlate with packages in C++ projects)

The problem is considerably exacerbated with inline template instantiation. Modern workstations aren't equipped to compile and link a project that pulls most of 5000 sizable classes together in either phase of the build.

The Java developers I've asked do not believe technical limitations are a reason to avoid circular package dependencies (other motivations apply). Are there any?

Comment: Regardless of technical limitations of Java, cyclical package dependencies can lead to a monolith. Avoiding them can be helpful.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer -- What is a "package dependency" in Java? I don't think there is such a thing (as far as the compiler is concerned).

Comment: @TedHopp - see the response to your similar comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The Java compiler (`javac`) does not compile all the classes at the same time, but rather one by one, dynamically discovering uncompiled or stale `.class` files.
2. There is no *linking*. Instead all the `.class` files are packaged together in a `jar` file once compiled. This is basically a ZIP compression and this step isn't even required.
3. The Java compiler is moderately simple due to simple language syntax and semantics. There isn't much metaprogramming, type inference, etc. Scala compiler, for example, is much slower because the language itself is much more complicated.

That being said I can't find any technical limitations of compiling large, tangled projects. Obviously the build time grows and once it exceeds 10 minutes it becomes a pain, but that isn't really an issue.

**The real problem** with tangled, circular, cross-references is source code maintainability. Mainly it is much harder to refactor code. Once the project reaches certain size (5000+ classes is probably around half million LOC) developers will try to split it into pieces. Extract libraries, modules and layers. If the dependencies are so strong, this process is close to impossible.

Comment: Suppose you have A.java and B.java, with no .class files. If class A depends on the existence of B.class to compile, and class B depends on the existence of A.class to compile, the compiler is going to compile them both at the same time (since the .class files simply cannot be generated sequentially). One strategy for a compiler would be to incrementally generate the .class files: do enough of A.class to compile B, then go back and finish A.class. In my book, that's still compiling them together.

Comment: Tomasz has it in a nutshell. It is not a compiler problem, it is a matter of good modularity. You would not put thousands of lines of code in a method, or thousands of methods in a class. You modularize in order to make the code easier to understand by a human developer. To stop at the class level is simply not scalable, you need higher level modules. Jars, beans, bundles, etc. serve this purpose, but when these contain more than a mindsized amount of classes, you need something in between, and packages are what you have in Java. And a module structure should be acyclic.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no such thing as package dependencies in Java. There are only class (and interface) dependencies. When you import a package in Java, you are only telling the compiler how to resolve names (so you don't need to fully qualify every class or static import name you use).

Circular dependencies between thousands of classes would probably bring a compiler to its knees.

Comment: That's a very strong statement. There is indeed such a thing as dependencies between Java packages, and tools exist to display them. You could say that the compiler ignores package dependencies.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer - What is a dependency between Java packages? What creates it? What effect does it have? As far as a package hierarchy is concerned, there's no semantic value to it as far as the Java language is concerned; it's strictly a code management tool.

Comment: Dependencies exist at multiple granularities, among methods, classes, packages, jar files. Some are relevant to the compiler, and some not. There is a difference between saying "this dependency has no effect in terms of the language / compiler" and saying "there is really no such thing as package dependencies."

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer -- I agree that packages can be related, but a dependency is a particular kind of relation, and not all relations are dependencies. There are also many kinds of dependencies: type; data; coupling (functional); definitional; etc. I'm just asking you to define what you mean.

Comment: I mean the kind of package dependencies which are displayed in Google's CodePro Analytix, or JDepends. :)